# Assigning variable to a JSON element in payload

Tags: arrays, json, list, file, python-3.x

How do I fix syntax error with variable assignment of data1? 'data1' variable prints out correctly but I get a syntax error when I place variable into JSON format prior to json.dumps into 'data' variable:

```
def queryFileID():

    with open('Payload.txt', 'r') as dd:
        payload = []
        for line in dd:
            payload.append(line)

    data1 = payload[0]

    data = json.dumps({
        "filters":{
        "op":"in",
        "content":{
            "field":"files.file_id",
                "value": data1 ,
                "format":"TSV",
                "fields":"case_id,",
                "size":"1000000",
    })

    with open('CaseIDs.txt', 'wb') as gdc:

        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(pycurl.URL, GDC_URL_legacy)
        c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json'])
        c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
        c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, gdc)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
```

Code that works:

```
import os
import pycurl
import json

GDC_URL_legacy = 'https://gdc-api.nci.nih.gov/legacy/files/'

data = json.dumps({
    "filters":{
        "op":"in",
        "content":{
            "field":"files.file_id",
            "value":
       ["6998b65f-568a-4636-a6cb-07fb23e984a7",]}},
    "format":"TSV",

"fields":"cases.case_id",
    "size":"1000000"
})

with open('CasedIDs.txt', 'wb') as tgc:

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, GDC_URL_legacy)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json'])
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, tgc)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Comment: Can you format the question to have only the necessary data?

Comment: What is throwing the syntax error? I assume it's a JSON syntax error. But we can't tell what it is without knowing what is inside the `Payload.txt` file.

Comment: Its a formatting issue between data1 --> json.dumps --> data.  I'm getting extra characters in the data file before it goes to the API. '  \ '....I'm going to have to remove all of these in 'data' variable before it gets sent to the API. This should do the trick. Now I just need to figure out best way to edit it..